# How to change Tabbackground and text in android viewpager?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (          String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this).setCustomView(R.layout.pager_title_strip));

        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:



            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
```

below is my xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i want to set TabPage with orange color and text should white color when it select else it should white i am trying fix it using    for (          String tab_name : tabs)

```
{
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this).setCustomView(R.layout.pager_title_strip));

        }
```

but i am unable to set back ground please help how to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the android:backgroundStacked attribute of the ActionBar style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
</style>
```

or (If using ActionBarSherlock):

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: where we have to add this  in style file of value folder?

Comment: ya in res->values->style

Comment: and the where we have to call but i want to make like this way how to cuomize it http://snag.gy/GjNiA.jpg

Comment: ya you can customize like this.you can specify style of it.

Comment: its showing error still i am unable to do this dear

Comment: when i put ur xml in style file can i have ur email id so that i will show u xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81967/discussion-between-research-development-and-kinjal).

Comment: will help you after some hour just try this way add some library and all will tell you within some hour

Comment: Ok thnkyu please give me step by stemp solution coz i tried sicnec morning

Comment: u there    did u check

Answer (score 0):

Call below function i.e. `updateSelectedTab(int position)` when activity launched first time  and pass "0" to its argument so that it'll show the very first tab selected by default.

Now call this function again inside `onPageSelected(int position)`. Before calling `updateSelected(position)` , make sure you have updated currently selected tabhost position. Just a code snippet that how will you do that :

```
    @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            updateSelected(position);
}




 public void updateSelectedTab(int position){

    for(int i = 1; i< getSupportActionBar().getTabCount(); i++) {
        if(i == position){
            ActionBar.Tab selectedTab = getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab();
            View selectedTabView = selectedTab.getCustomView();
            selectedTabView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7F2A"));
            TextView tv = (TextView) selectedTabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }else {
            ActionBar.Tab restTab = getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(i);
            View restTabView = restTab.getCustomView();
            restTabView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            TextView tv = (TextView) restTabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }


}
```

Also make sure your pager_title_strip.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Also, I haven't tested it, I think it should work anyway. Good Luck :)